# Upgrade Jenkins 1.486 (12.04) to latest build from jenkins-ci.org

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, jenkins

I am wondering whether it is possible to upgrade a Jenkins 1.486 installation (on Ubuntu 12.04, official repository) to the latest version offered on [jenkins-ci.org](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/). I really need to upgrade because of some bugs but I do not dare to install the new version via "apt-get dist-upgrade" or "dpkg -i....".

Upgrading the whole system to Ubuntu 14.xx is not an option, because a) the server has no internet connection (local apt-mirror) and b) jenkins was removed from the ubuntu repositories in 2014. :(

I would just give it a try but the server is production system. It should not fail. ;)
Has anyone had any experience with this upgrade?

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Ok, I simply replaced the WAR file under /usr/share/jenkins with the current one from jenkins-ci.org and restarted jenkins. After manually updating two plugins everything seems to work. :)